# Not enough arguments - what is the difference

Tags: python

I have two almost identical programs. One works, the other does not. The program that is not working displays the error "not enough arguments for format string". It probably has something to do with the "%" in the variable dbname, but I can't figure out why one program works and the other does not. In both programs I'm attempting to use a wildcard in a SELECT statement with LIKE.

Working program:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import commands
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Date, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine      
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

engine = create_engine('mysql://UID:PASS@999.999.99.99:9999/access_benchmark_staging', echo=True)
dest = engine.connect()
dest.execute("truncate table TABAUTH")


def dbapull(applid, ssid, host, port, dbname):
    print "dbapull " + dbname + ""
    source = pyodbc.connect('Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=' + ssid +';Hostname=' + host + ';Port=' + port + ';Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=user;Pwd=password', echo=True)
    src = source.cursor()
    src.execute("SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(CURRENT SERVER,1,7) AS SSID, SUBSTR(B.GRANTEE,1,8) AS GRANTEE, B.UPDATEAUTH AS U, B.INSERTAUTH AS I, B.DELETEAUTH AS D, A.CREATOR, B.DBNAME, B.TTNAME, B.ALTERAUTH AS C FROM " + ssid + ".SYSIBM.SYSTABLES A LEFT JOIN " + ssid + ".SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH B ON A.CREATOR = B.TCREATOR AND A.NAME = B.TTNAME WHERE A.CREATOR IN ('PFPROD','PGPROD','PSPROD','PS','PROD') AND A.DBNAME LIKE " + dbname + " AND (B.UPDATEAUTH <> ' ' OR  B.INSERTAUTH <> ' ' OR  B.DELETEAUTH <> ' ') AND A.TYPE IN ('T','V') AND B.GRANTEETYPE = ' ' AND A.NAME NOT IN ('DSN_VIEWREF_TABLE','DSN_PGRANGE_TABLE','DSN_SORTKEY_TABLE','DSN_SORT_TABLE','DSN_DETCOST_TABLE','DSN_FILTER_TABLE','DSN_PTASK_TABLE','DSN_STATEMNT_TABLE','DSN_PGROUP_TABLE','DSN_STRUCT_TABLE','DSN_PREDICAT_TABLE','PLAN_TABLE') ORDER BY 2")
    for row in src:
       #print (row)
       row[0] = str(row[0]).strip()
       row[1] = str(row[1]).strip()
       row[2] = str(row[2]).strip()
       row[3] = str(row[3]).strip()
       row[4] = str(row[4]).strip()
       row[5] = str(row[5]).strip()
       row[6] = str(row[6]).strip()
       row[7] = str(row[7]).strip()
       row[8] = str(row[8]).strip()
       result = dest.execute("insert ignore into TABAUTH values ('" + applid + "','" + row[0] + "','" + row[1] + "','" + row[2] + "','" + row[3] + "','" + row[4] + "','" + row[5] + "','" + row[6] + "','" + row[7] + "','" + row[8] + "')")

dbapull("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "'%PMC%'")

dest.close()
```

Non-working program:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import commands
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Date, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine      
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

engine = create_engine('mysql://UID:PASS@999.999.99.99:9999/access_benchmark_staging', echo=True)
dest = engine.connect()
dest.execute("truncate table DS_Users")


def userpull(appl, dbname):
    print "DS User pull " + dbname + " "
    source = create_engine('mysql://UID:PASS@999.999.99.99:9999/access_benchmark_staging', echo=True)
    src = engine.connect()
    src.execute("SELECT MF.profile_name AS profile_name, MF.groupuser_access as groupuser_access, MF.group_id as group_id, MF.user_id as user_id, MF.user_name as user_name, MF.default_group as default_group, MF.last_racinit as last_racinit, MF.password_last_changed_date as password_last_changed_date, MF.user_id_status as user_id_status, MF.creation_date as creation_date, ldap.uid as uid, ldap.company as company, ldap.emp_name as emp_name, ldap.title as title, ldap.contract_exp as contact_exp, ldap.dept_name as dept_name, ldap.emp_status as emp_status, ldap.disabled_date as disabled_date, ldap.term_date as term_date, ldap.bus_unit as bus_unit, ldap.manager_id as manager_id FROM (SELECT DST.profile_name, DST.groupuser_access, GRP.group_id, USR.user_id, USR.user_name, USR.default_group, USR.last_racinit, USR.password_last_changed_date, USR.user_id_status, USR.creation_date FROM AU_KRC_USER_REPORT USR INNER JOIN AU_KRC_GROUP_REPORT GRP ON USR.user_id = GRP.user_id INNER JOIN AU_KRC_DATASET_REPORT DST ON GRP.group_id = DST.groupuser_id WHERE (DST.profile_name LIKE " + dbname + " AND DST.profile_name NOT IN ('" + appl + ".SYSINFO.ABEND')) AND DST.groupuser_access IN ('UPDAT', 'ALTER') AND DST.groupuser_type = 'GROUP' ) MF LEFT OUTER JOIN ldap.ldap_raw ldap ON MF.user_id = ldap.kmart_mf GROUP BY MF.group_id, MF.user_id, MF.user_name, MF.default_group, MF.last_racinit, MF.password_last_changed_date, MF.user_id_status, MF.creation_date, ldap.uid, ldap.company, ldap.emp_name,ldap.title, ldap.contract_exp, ldap.dept_name, ldap.emp_status, ldap.disabled_date, ldap.term_date, ldap.bus_unit, ldap.manager_id")
    for row in src:
        #print (row)
        row[0] = str(row[0]).strip()
        row[1] = str(row[1]).strip()
        row[2] = str(row[2]).strip()
        row[3] = str(row[3]).strip()
        row[4] = str(row[4]).strip()
        row[5] = str(row[5]).strip()
        row[6] = str(row[6]).strip()
        row[7] = str(row[7]).strip()
        row[8] = str(row[8]).strip()
        row[9] = str(row[9]).strip()
        row[10] = str(row[10]).strip()
        row[11] = str(row[11]).strip()
        row[12] = str(row[12]).strip()
        row[13] = str(row[13]).strip()
        row[14] = str(row[14]).strip()
        row[15] = str(row[15]).strip()
        row[16] = str(row[16]).strip()
        row[17] = str(row[17]).strip()
        row[18] = str(row[18]).strip()
        row[19] = str(row[19]).strip()
        row[20] = str(row[20]).strip()
        result = dest.execute("insert ignore into DS_Users values ('" + appl +"','" + row[0] + "','" + row[1] + "','" + row[2] + "','" + row[3] + "','" + row[4] + "','" + row[5] + "','" + row[6] + "','" + row[7] + "','" + row[8] + "','" + row[9] + "','" + row[10] + "','" + row[11] + "','" + row[12] + "','" + row[13] + "','" + row[14] + "','" + row[15] + "','" + row[16] + "','" + row[17] + "','" + row[18] + "','" + row[19] + "','" + row[20] + "')")

userpull("PP", "'%PP.%'")
```

Comment: way too much code here, come up with a minimal example

Comment: yuck, no formatting.  Unreadable

Comment: Did you try to isolate the problem? This is too messy to try to debug it as it is. I suggest you replace the arguments by dummies, making the problem more readable until you find the bug.

Comment: Thanks for formatting.  Now please give us the exact traceback that the "not enough arguments for format string" generates

Comment: "Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters." - PEP 8 If you're not going to follow basic style guidelines, then why are you using this language?

Comment: DRY - repetition is the root of all evil. 21 lines of this: `row[20] = str(row[20]).strip()` is a sure sign you're doing something terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your sql in a transaction and check if the driver you are using for the DB support the "%" for queries.

Comment: At least this suggestion had a constructive suggestion. Yes, I tried running the query directly in MySQL Workbench with the % and it returned the desired results. I'm still new to PYTHON and don't have all the bells and whistles worked out to an exact science. The coding may not be pretty, but that doesn't explain why it works in one instance and not another.

Comment: Here is the traceback - I "hope" this is in the right format.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 183, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: I found the solution. The % needed to be in pairs. I changed the parameter to "'PP.%%'" and it worked.  Granted, the rest of the code needs to be "cleaned up", but at least I'm getting the desired results.